# Kendo DateTimePicker ParseFormats not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Telerik Kendo UI Framework in my ASP.NET MVC project, and I would like to enable a feature which let user to input free text in the DateTimePicker input, for eg: *20150820,  20150820 1330*, etc.

Kendo DateTimePicker has built-in attributes called "[parseFormats](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datetimepicker#configuration-parseFormats)" to achieve this task. However it fails in following case:

```
<input ... data-parse-foramts="['ddMMyyyy HHmm','ddMMyyyy', 
'dd-MM-yyyy', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm', 'yyyyMMdd', 'yyyyMMdd HHmm']" ... />
```

The last value let user to type free text like *20152020 1330* and it should be parsed as **2015-20-20 13:30**, however the **time part (13:30) does not work**, the control always shows **00:00**. All other included formats work as expected.

While I try to simplified the formats to `data-parse-formats="['yyyyMMdd HHmm']"`, then everything goes fine.

Why is this happening, and how can I implement the feature I want?

Comment: It is mentioned in the documentation that the order should be `Order of the provided parse formats is important and it should from stricter to less strict.`. It looks you have overruled this condition in your case. You are moving from less strict to stricter! Refer : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/timepicker#configuration-parseFormats

Comment: @Vijai Thanks..how could I miss that sentence...You saved my life!

Comment: You should now answer your question to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Vijai mentioned in the comment, the key point of the problem is that, the parse formats array should have a strict order:

> Order of the provided parse formats is important and it should from stricter to less strict.

Which means `yyyyMMdd HHmmtt` should place before `yyyyMMdd` and etc.

Here is my refined parse formats which work fine for all included formats:

`['ddMMyyyy HHmm', 'yyyyMMdd HHmm', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm', 'dd-MM-yyyy',  'yyyyMMdd', 'ddMMyyyy', 'HHmm']`